# Is possible to generate a circle tangental to another circle and a line in this way?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I'm looking to get some help with a math conundrum i've been tackling for a while.

Suppose I have a large circle (A), with radius R, where the centre point of the circle sits on the centre of a cartesian plane (0,0). I define a point (D) anywhere outside of this circle and I know the coordinates of this point, e.g. (0,-100). I also define a point (C) that is the closest point on the circle to D, whose coordinates I also know e.g. (0,-70).

What I want to do is calculate the position of a second circle (E) with any known radius that is tangental to both the large circle A, and the line defined by C and D. The result I want to calculate is either the cartesian coordinate of circle E's centre, or the required angle from AC to get this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. You can assume that the angular position of the line from A to C is also known e.g. 180 degrees. (it can be anything).

Comment: Why did you delete your older posting of the same question two days ago and then repost here now?

Comment: Because my previous question was badly formulated and no one was replying to it, as it was down in the queue.

Comment: @LeonFargher: Deleting-and-reposting is not the appropriate way to bring attention to a question (or to escape down- and/or close-votes, if they were happening). Rather, you should edit the original version to improve its quality (improving formatting, adding context like where you got stuck in solving this yourself, etc). An edit will "bump" a question to the top of the Unanswered queue, so you get that benefit of reposting without potentially confusing anyone. ... There's probably no harm done here, but keep this in mind for the future. Cheers! :)

Comment: Okay thank you I didnt realise, will do so in future

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the radius of the second circle is $r$. Then the distance between the two centers is going to be $R+r$. Draw the perpendicular from the center of circle E to the CD line, say to point $P$. Then $P$ and the two centers form a right angle triangle. The distance from center of E to $P$ is $r$ (tangent), the hypotenuse is $R+r$, and the distance between $P$ and origin is $x$. Then $$(R+r)^2=x^2+r^2$$ so $$x^2=R(R+2r)$$
Then the Cartesian coordinate of the center of E are $(-x,\pm r)$, assuming that D is at $(-d,0)$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is great, I will test this out. I was so focused on trying to find a relationship between the two circles I didn't think of the triangular relationship

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Can you find the right triangle that has the unknown radius in it and use Pythagoras theorem?

$$ r_E=r;\quad AE=\sqrt{(AD+DC)^2-CE^2} =\sqrt{(R+r)^2-r^2} = \sqrt{R(R+2r)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image: Center of Circle]

In this answer, we describe a simple geometric construction, which allows you to graphically determine the location of point $E$, the center of the smaller of the two circle. We assume that the radii of the small (green) and the large (red) circles are known and equal to $r$ and $R$ respectively. The only other thing known to us is the straight line $AD$, where $A$ is the center of the larger circle.

First, construct the line perpendicular to $AD$ through $A$ and mark $F$ on this line such that $AF = r$. Then, draw a line $FG$ parallel to $AD$ through $F$. Finally, taking $A$ as the center draw an auxiliary circle having radius equal to $R+r$. Location of the point $E$, is the intersection between this auxiliary circle and the line $FG$. Note that the line $EA$, which joins the two centers, passes through the point of tangency between the two circles

In order to analytically determine the position of point $E$, we need to draw the line $EB$ which is perpendicular to $AD$ and equal to the $y$-coordinate of $E$. This makes $\triangle EBA$ a right angle triangle, in which the sides $EB$ and $EA$ are known to be equal to $r$ and $R+r$ respectively. As described in @Andrei's answer, using Pythagoras’s theorem, you can calculate the length of $AB$, which is equal to the $x$-coordinate of $E$.